# Multiple if statements not recognised

Tags: python-3.x

The script is suppose to log into the Cisco device (via console port), look for a matching `if` statement and execute the corresponding code.

The script currently only attempts to match the first `if` statement and ignores the rest.

How would it be possible for the script to search down the list of `if` statements and execute the relevant one?

```
# $language = "python"
# $interface = "1.0"

# Connect to an SSH server using the SSH2 protocol. Specify the
# username and password and hostname on the command line as well as
# some SSH2 protocol specific options.
# msgbox = crt.Dialog.MessageBox

def main():
# Prompt for a password instead of embedding it in a script...
#
# passwd = crt.Dialog.Prompt("Enter password for " + host, "Login", "", True)
      passwd = crt.Dialog.Prompt

# Build a command-line string to pass to the Connect method.
cmd = "/SERIAL COM6 /BAUD 9600 /NOCTS /DATA 8 /NODSR /PARITY NONE /NOXON"
crt.Session.Connect(cmd, False)
crt.Screen.Synchronous = True
# This line will need to be modified to wait for what the remote will send.
crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))

initial_1 = crt.Screen.WaitForString("outer")
initial_2 = crt.Screen.WaitForString("initial configuration dialog")
initial_3 = crt.Screen.WaitForString("con0")
initial_4 = crt.Screen.WaitForString("odified")
initial_5 = crt.Screen.WaitForString("Press RETURN to get started")


if initial_1 == True:
      crt.Screen.Send("en" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("Password", 2)
      crt.Screen.Send("groovy" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
      crt.Screen.Send("erase startup-config" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("Erasing")
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
      crt.Screen.Send("delete nvram:vlan.dat" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("vlan.dat")
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("confirm")
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
      crt.Screen.Send("reload" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("System configuration has been modified", 2)
      crt.Screen.Send("no" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("Proceed with reload", 2)
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))

if initial_2 == True:
      crt.Screen.Send("no" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("Would you like to terminate autoinstall", 3)
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))

if initial_3 == True:
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("rt1")
      crt.Screen.Send("en" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("Password")
      crt.Screen.Send("groovy" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
      crt.Screen.Send("erase startup-config" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("Erasing")
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
      crt.Screen.Send("delete nvram:vlan.dat" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("vlan.dat")
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("confirm")
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
      crt.Screen.Send("reload" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))

if initial_4 == True:
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("confirm")
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))

if initial_5 == True:
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      #
      crt.Screen.Send("en" + chr(13))
      #
      crt.Screen.Send("delete flash:vlan.dat" + chr(13))
      #
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.Send(chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
      #
      crt.Screen.Send("config t" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("config")
      #
      crt.Screen.Send("interface Cellular0/1/0" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("config")
      crt.Screen.Send("shut" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("config")
      #
      crt.Screen.Send("end" + chr(13))
      crt.Screen.WaitForString("#")
```

Comment: "The script currently only attempts to match the first IF statement and ignores the rest."
How can you tell? What if `initial_2`, `3`,... are simply `False`? Also, those `== True` are unnecessary. Simply check for `if initial_1:`

Comment: You mean that you don't know why `initial_2` through `initial_5` are `False` perhaps? Because Python statements don't just change behaviour half-way through the program; the `if` statements don't execute their suites because the condition is not being met.

Comment: Not sure how this program is supposed to work exactly. What is `crt.Screen.WaitForString` doing? It seems like you want to react to events, but your program will evaluate those conditions only once, when the program starts.